# URLConnection in java using username, password, token

Tags: java, passwords, token, urlconnection

I am trying to Connect to url using URLConnection, in java with username and password.
This is the following code I am using:

```
package com.nivi.org.client;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import com.sun.jersey.core.util.Base64;

public class GetURLContent {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        URL url;

        try {

            url = new URL("http://sampleurl.co.uk");

            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();


            String username = "username";
            String password = "password";
            String Token = "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";


            System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "proxyhostname");
            System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");


            String userpass = username + ":" + password;
            String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(new Base64().encode(userpass.getBytes()));
            conn.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
            conn.setRequestProperty ("Token", Token);


            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                               new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            System.out.println("br............."+br.toString());

            br.close();

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

=======================================
I am getting the following error

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL:
http://sampleurl.co.uk
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1625)
    at com.nivi.org.client.GetURLContent.main(GetURLContent.java:63)
```

=======================================

First of all my question is 
Are these following lines in the code are correct?

```
  conn.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
  conn.setRequestProperty ("Token", Token);
```

Comment: may i know which protocal u r using HHTP or https , and your are passing user name only , so you should pass user name including passowrd , for aunthentication purpose we should  pass both values .

Comment: You should use a `java.net.Authenticator` for this.

Comment: @savan Read the code. He is passing both, and HTTP or HTTPS makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

> Are these following lines in the code are correct?

It depends on how the actual website you are accessing implements its user authentication.

What you appear to be doing is a combination of HTTP Basic Authentication (i.e. the `Authorization` header), and something involving a non-standard header called `Token`.  This may be sufficient, if the website supports Basic Authentication.

---

You should probably read the website's programmer documentation of how their web APIs work.  If there isn't any such documentation available to you, use your browsers web development tools to identify the mechanism that the site is using when you log in via a web browser ... and attempt to get your client to behave the same way.

---

One thing to note is that sending a Basic authorization response in an HTTP request is insecure.  Use an HTTPS request if that is an option.